# play , pause , stop music with UIActionSheet

Tags: uiactionsheet, audio-player

I am Newbie to Xcode and I need some experience from who mastered xcode .
I Am trying to play , pause , stop Music with an UIActionSheet but when I click in Pause and Stop button they don't stop or even Pause only Play button works.Can someone help me with it ?
Here is my code.

```
 #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
 @interface MainViewController () <UIActionSheetDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
 @property(nonatomic,retain)AVAudioPlayer *playAudio;
 @end

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonTitle =[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    NSURL *url =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MusicName.mp3",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;

    self.playAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

    if (buttonIndex==0) {

        [self.playAudio play];

    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Pause"]) {

        [self.playAudio pause];
    }
    if (buttonIndex==2) {
        [self.playAudio stop];
    }
}
- (IBAction)Music:(id)sender {

    UIActionSheet *musicSheet =[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Choose" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Play",@"Pause",@"Stop", nil];
    [musicSheet showInView:self.view];


}
```

. I am a Vietnamese so my English skills can make you hard to understand what I say. Thank you for your time . I am looking forward to seeing your reply

Answer (score 0):

First of all : you should not rely on the button title. Use  the button index to identify which button is pressed, that's what it's for.

Second :
Are you sure the index of your buttons is right ? You may try using a switch statement.

Such as :

```
switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            [self.playAudio play];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self.playAudio pause];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self.playAudio stop];
            break;
        default:
            break;
}
```

Comment: Tks for your answer I'll try then I'll tell you later

Comment: ... nah still not work even when I used switch statement.Do I have to set delegate for each buttonIndex ? I tried to set delegate before the switch statement but it still not work